# How to call a action by route specified over action in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

MVC controller code is:

```
[Route("Home-Appliances")]
public async Task<ActionResult> homeappliances(string q = "", string tags = null, int minPrice = 0, int maxPrice = 50000, bool accessories = false, string condition = null, int? page = null)
{
     //my stuff...       
}
```

How can I call this method from view using html helpers?

Note: I don't want to call this by action name. I have to call this by route specified i.e, `Home-Appliances`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Home-Appliances" is not the route name, it's the URL. If you want to call it by route name, you need to pass a name:

```
[Route("Home-Appliances", Name = "HomeAppliances")]
```

Then, you can do:

```
Url.RouteUrl("HomeAppliances")
```